# Remove Snooze -button in Android Alarm-lock

Tags: alarm

I always by accident hit the Snooze button instead of Alarm -and it is irritating, alarm starting afterwards again. Is there some better alarm -lock with better UI or how can I remove the alarm-lock "Snooze" that is totally useless?

Comment: Check out alarmdroid: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.splunchy.android.alarmclock

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Alarm Clock Xtreme](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alarmclock.xtreme.free). Its reliable & it has everything you want.